# RSpecのletは作りなおしてしまってよい？

Tags: rspec

RSpec3です。

下記のようにletを上書き？（オーバーライド？）してしまって問題ないのでしょうか？
（このletの使い方の正しい用語が不明です。　オーバーライド？　作り直し？）
動作的には問題なかったのですが、マニュアル等で言及されているものが見つけられませんでした。

用途としては、多くの`context`でほとんど共通なのですが、極小数のパターンで上書きしたい場合（わざと異常なデータを入れる）を想定しています。

```
  describe '#hoge' do
    let(:hoge) { 'hoge' }
    subject { hoge }

    context 'case 1' do
      let(:hoge) { 'hoge1' }
      it { is_expected.to eq 'hoge1' }
    end

    context 'case 2' do
      let(:hoge) { 'hoge2' }
      it { is_expected.to eq 'hoge2' }
    end
  end
```

Comment: 「問題なのでは？」と思われた理由はなんでしょうか？普通の使い方だと思います. 参考:  http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/42193d066bd61c740612#let-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E6%B4%BB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-age-%E3%82%82-let-%E3%81%A7%E7%BD%AE%E3%81%8D%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B

Comment: 参考のものは contextの中にしかlet(:age)がありませんよね。私の例だと、let(:hoge)が contextの中と外に存在しています。なので、ネットで見かけない例だと思って気になりました。